# Bluez Installation - configuration error for DBUS 1.6

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, bluetooth, compiling, dbus

I am trying to install bluez 5.2 libraries on Ubuntu 12.04. while running `./configure`, I received error for GLib2.0, I was able to resolve by using `sudo apt get-install` for GLib2. Now I am receiving the error `"configure: error: D-Bus >= 1.6 is required"`. I have downloaded DBUS 1.8.6 and installed. but still I am receiving the same error. when checked in `/etc` folder i still find dbus-1.
is there any installation error?

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to compile bluez from sources? Did you tried just `sudo apt-get build-dep bluez` and compiling? Which version of Bluez are you trying to compile? [Edit] your question and include the complete output of `./configure`.

Comment: I am trying with bluetooth programming in Linux as a for my curriculum project.

Comment: You probably need `libdbus-1-dev` or `libdbus-c++-dev` or something like that.

Comment: I am trying to enable bluetooth (Ubuntu Version 13.10), in system settings and seeing this message "No Bluetooth Adapters found:

Comment: You need to install the headers, the -dev packages

Comment: the actual problem I am facing is in system settings, when I click on Bluetooth settings, it says No Bluetooth Adapters found. when I checked in terminal, I find all drivers are installed. when I invoked hcitool dev, it says no devices found. So I doubt that some settings of drivers are missing to activate Bluetooth.

Answer (score 18):

Installing `libdbus-1-dev` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 10):

Install the headers and libraries required for Bluez compilation:

```
sudo apt install libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev
```

For more info:
https://codeyarns.com/2017/06/05/how-to-build-and-install-bluez/

Answer (score -1):

Sorted out this problem. First of all I ran

```
sh -x ./configure 2>errors.txt
```

The `errors.txt` showed me what command was failing which was

```
/usr/bin/pkg-config --short-errors --print-errors --cflag --libs 'dbus-1 >= 1.6'
```

After further digging it seems a file `dbus-1.pc` was not where it was supposed to be

After locating the file and copying to the correct location

```
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, Can i know from which path i need to run sh -x ./configure 2>errors.txt ?. I have logged in as root

Comment: Hi all, Thanks for your suggestions and help. I am able to install Blue-z libraries. The actual problem i was facing "Bluetooth Adapter not found", was solved by switching back to windows and turning on bluetooth adapter in Windows.